# redirect to 404 error page which urls contain "page.php?"

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect http://www.yourdomain.com/page.php? or http://www.yourdomain.com/page.php?var=val to 404 error page using `.htaccess`.

I have used this code

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php\?.*$ /404.shtml [R=404,L]
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the query string from a RewriteRule directive.
If you want to detect `var=val` or `?` (empty query string) use

```
#if query string has var=val
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=val [NC,OR]
#or it just has ? with no query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} page\.php\?\  [NC]
#and resource is page.php serve 404
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /404.shtml [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: It is also redirecting "http:///www.yourdomain.com/page.php" I just want for "http:///www.yourdomain.com/page.php?". If it contains  "?" at the end